# Can lifecycle events be observed without annotation processing in the new Android Lifecycle Architecture component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

annotation processing/code generation adds significant overhead to build times and breaks incremental builds.

Can I (reactively, aka not by manually forwarding events) get a fine-grained callback for `Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP` using the [Android Lifecycle Architecure Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html)?

Or does this use reflection (slow) if I choose not to use annotation processing?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to implement the `GenericLifecycleObserver` interface and then capture the events in the `onStateChanged` method.